# get input form not as variable but as url

Tags: html, url, flask, get

I am building a webservice so people can search into the database. Lets say I have users and companies. Each user and company can be found thought their id. So if you search `myurl/users/<id>` you get information of that user, on the other hand if you search company/ you get information of that company.
For this I have created two simple input texts (one for users and another for companies) where people can type the `<id>`. My problem is that when I get the value from the input text I get this `myrul/users?<id>` and not `myurl/users/id`. I tried to hardcode the slash but then I get `myrul/users/?<id>`.
So my question is how can I get input text as a url and not as a variable.

I am using flask so my html has jinja2 code like this:

```
<!-- USER id -->
    <form method='GET' action={{url_for('get_info_by_id', type_collection='user')}}>
        <input type="text" name="my_id"/><input type="submit" value="Go">                         
    </form>

<!-- COMPANY id-->
    <form method='GET' action={{url_for('get_info_by_id', type_collection='company')}}>
        <input type="text" name="my_id"/><input type="submit" value="Go">                      
    </form>
```

In my python script (flask)

```
@app.route('myurl/<type_collection>/<my_id>')
get_info_by_id(type_collection,my_id):
    # search into the database and return info about that id
```

Comment: If you want form variables to be placed within the URL rather than the query string or post body, you'll need to use JavaScript to capture the form submission event and navigate to the new URL.

Comment: @dirn is correct, however look at my answer if you are just trying to get your form to search the database and return your objects.

Comment: I will go through JavaScript, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dirn suggested in the commentary, I made it through JavaScript, here is the code if someone else is also interested:

HTML:

```
<!-- USER id -->
<form method='GET' class="search" id="user" action="">
    <input type="text" name="my_id"/><input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>

<!-- COMPANY id-->
<form method='GET' class="search" id="company" action="">
    <input type="text" name="my_id"/><input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(".search").submit(function( event ){
    event.preventDefault();
    var my_id = $(this).find(":input").val();
    url = 'myurl/'+ $(this).attr("id") + '/' + my_id;
    window.location.href = url;     
});
```

python (flask)

```
@app.route('myurl/<type_collection>/<my_id>')
get_info_by_id(type_collection,my_id):
    # search into the database and return info about that id
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you cannot use the variable, or are you just trying to get it into a URL so that you can do your search?  I went out on a limb and assumed you just want the form and database search to work, so try the following out.

Adjust your route like so:

```
@app.route('myurl/<type_collection>/')
def findAllTheThings():
    if not request.form['my_id']: # Just check if a specific entity is chosen
        return render_template('YourTemplateHere') # If no entity, then render form 
    entity_id = request.form['my_id']
    get_info_by_id(type_collection, entity_id):
    # search into the database and return info about that id
```

Now adjust the template as follows:

```
<!-- USER id -->
<form method='GET' action={{url_for('findAllTheThings', type_collection='user')}}>
    <input type="text" name="my_id"/><input type="submit" value="Go">                         
</form>

<!-- COMPANY id-->
<form method='GET' action={{url_for('findAllTheThings', type_collection='company')}}>
    <input type="text" name="my_id"/><input type="submit" value="Go">                      
</form>
```

Now, if no entity has been selected you'll just render the form.  You can throw in a flash to let them know they need to select a specific ID, or just let them figure it out.  If an entity has been selected, you will call the fucntion correctly.

Comment: thank you but I do need to make it as an url and not as a variable